# Response.Redirect() to redirect to a page in a subfolder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, relative-path, response.redirect

I am using a `Response.Redirect("login.aspx");`

Since I moved my `login.aspx` to my `Account` subfolder, I tried the following code, however it doesn't work.

```
Response.Redirect("Account/login.aspx");
```

The URL this tries to redirect to this:

```
http://localhost/BuzzEnhance/Account/Login.aspx
```

The full code is:

```
public partial class BuzzMaster : MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["Username"] != null)
            {
                username.Text = Session["Username"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Account/Login.aspx");
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

and one more thing both the default page and login page use the same master page.

Comment: -1 for not even trying to post readable question.

Comment: At least paste code without spelling errors (English errors are acceptable, but what you posted has typoes on `response` everywhere and the URL you post and the redirect line don't match up)

Comment: edited .. i need to go from root folder to subfolder name Accont and to a page named login.aspx .. how to

Comment: @ShadowWizard now read it ...

Comment: Still full with errors, including your code.

Comment: That's got to be one of the fuller edits I've ever done!

Comment: @Jon good job - user614946, please see what Jon did and do the same in the future. Posting full code is not what anyone here asked and really not relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you're doing a redirect from a MasterPage, and using a relative path.

When you use a relative path, it will be relative to the location of the content page that is bound to the master page, *not*  relative to the location of the Master Page.

Your redirection to :

```
/BuzzEnhance/Account/Account/Login.aspx
```

is almost certainly coming from a content page in the Account folder that is bound to your master page.  For example, if your Login page (/BuzzEnhance/Account/Login.aspx) is itself bound to that Master page, it will redirect to the relative path `Account/Login.aspx`, which will resolve to `/BuzzEnhance/Account/Account/Login.aspx`, exactly what you're seeing.

The best solution is in the answer from @abatishchev - use a path relative to the application root `~/Account/Login.aspx`.

However, this will give you another problem if, as I suspect, your Login.aspx page is bound to the same master page.  Each time you access Login.aspx, it will execute the redirect code in the master page, resulting in an infinite loop until something times out.

One solution is either to avoid binding your Login.aspx page to that Master page, or to add some conditional code so you don't redirect when on the Login.aspx page.

Though even better, you should not need to do a redirect at all if you use Forms Authentication and leave it to manage redirection to the login page in the standard way.  If you want to display the username, you can use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` - or use one of the ASP.NET Login controls: `LoginStatus`, `LoginName`, ...

Answer (score 5):

```
"~/Account/Login.aspx"
```

will give

```
"<app root>/Account/Login.aspx"
```

so if your apps' root is

```
http://localhost/BuzzEnhance
```

the relative path given will be expanded to

```
http://localhost/BuzzEnhance/Account/Login.aspx
```

---

Also if you're using Forms Authentication, you may want to use

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirecttologinpage.aspx).

Comment: @ShadowWizard it still HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.

Comment: @user614946: Note that I've removed port number as being unimportant.

Comment: @user614946: Does url `http://<any>/BuzzEnhance/Account/Login.aspx` really exist?

Comment: yes the folder is there and the file Login.aspx is in it ... i cant figure it out that why i posted it in here ..@ShadowWizard

Comment: @user614946: `Account/Account/Login.aspx` or just `Account/Login.aspx` ?!

Comment: just Account/Login.aspx @abatishchev

Comment: @user614946: then `"~/Account/Login.aspx"` should work. Try use `Server.MapPath(string)` to check how is `~` being expended.

Comment: i dont know why its not working .. i am using my above given code .. and "~/Account/Login.aspx but i get problem loading page!

Comment: @user614946: Have you tried `Server.MapPath()` to debug resulting path?

Comment: @abatishchev yes and it gives me the path but of my machine .. when i give our method a try it say problem loading page.. and no auths ..

Comment: @user614946 - "...it say problem loading page." probably because Login.aspx is bound to the Master page, and it's looping - see my answer.

Comment: @user614946: Yes, it's so it works: converts relative web path to physical, so you could check does it really exist, etc. Does it?

Answer (score 2):

First of all its not `responce.redirect("page.aspx");`

its `Response.Redirect("Page.aspx");`

Try in this way it will work. As per your question its `Response.Redirect("folder/page.aspx");` try now, I will be waiting.

Keep in mind in C# first letter should be capitalized.

Comment: Problem is the page with the code is already inside different sub folder, called "BuzzEnhance" so the relative path is relative to that location.

Comment: @ShadowWizard so now what should i do??

Comment: @user614946: Post the whole app folder structure, please.

Comment: BuzzEnhance\Account\Login.aspx .. i tested when i put it in the root and call only response.redirect("login.aspx"); page is called .. but when placed in Account folder which is in the root folder it gives error @abatishchev

Answer (score 1):

What you need is this:

```
Response.Redirect("/Account/Login.aspx");
```

This will go to `Account` that reside inside the root and in there to `Login.aspx` page.

Comment: no luck with that it gives me http://localhost:10773/Account/Login.aspx but what i need is http://localhost:10773/BuzzEnhance/Account/Login.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Response.Redirect(this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Account/Login.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

OP says

*"Since I moved my `login.aspx` to my `Account` subfolder, I tried the following code, however it doesn't work."*

**There is another case that might cause exactly some behavior.**
In the `web.config` you might have permitted locations. And unless you open one such location that you've added, you will not be redirected there

```xml
<location path="Account/login.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Once above ^^ is set, this `Response.Redirect("~/Account/login.aspx");` certainly works