# Response.Redirect preserves the subdirectory of the web

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have the following code to redirect when the session timeouts, called in a Master Page.

```
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
```

For some reason, it works on development machine but not on the web servers.

Assume that the website root is `http://mywebsite.com/`.

If I am at `http://mywebsite.com/foo/bar/page.aspx` and timeout happens, the page is redirecting to `http://mywebsite.com/foo/bar/Login.aspx` instead of `http://mywebsite.com/Login.aspx`, hence throwing page not found exception.

What is wrong?

Comment: have you disabled directory listing from iis ?

Comment: It is currently disabled.

Comment: Hope you also put Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)  this to you each page_load event

Comment: I avoid putting some code to each page_load, it will be a tremendous work to do so. If it can be done globally in one file / there is a config, it will be great.

Comment: you can do it in global.asax, inside  Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute event.

Comment: I tried, but it does not work.

Comment: Is this the answer you're looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551535/response-redirect-to-redirect-to-a-page-in-a-subfolder

Comment: @T.S. I'm already using the "~" sign which should resolve to the root of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find a solution to this problem. The solution is to add the following code in `Session_Start` function in `Global.asax.cs`.

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
```

Previously, my code was without `~/`, so that's why it does not redirect to the web root.

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

It seems that even though I already call `Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");` in the Master Page, I still need to put this code in `Session_Start` too.